# How to change column wise data into row wise in excel using python (consider records in Millions)

Tags: python, pandas

How to change column wise data into row wise in excel using python (consider records in Millions)

Input

```
StuId  Name     Subject
1      Adam      French
1      Adam      English 
1      Adam      Science
2      Jon        Maths
2      Jon        French
```

Output expected:

```
 StuId     Name       Subjects
  1        Adam       French    English   Science
  2         Jon       Maths     French
```

Thanks

Comment: In order to kick start a meaningful conversation, you need to specify how you parse this data and what your internal structure is.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=' '.join`.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['StuId','Name'], values=['Subject'], 
                    aggfunc=' '.join).reset_index()
print(df)
```

---

```
   StuId  Name                  Subject
0      1  Adam  French English  Science
1      2   Jon             Maths French
```

Answer (score 0):

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-t-transpose/

Go through this site. clear answer to Your Question

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the other columns and aggregate the subjects using a `list` -

```py
 df.groupby(['StuId', 'Name']).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)))
```

**Output**

```
                           Subject
StuId Name                        
1     Adam  French English Science
2     Jon             Maths French
```